# Удаление добавление классов

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы при зажатой мышки выделялись элементы и так-же только при зажатой становились прежними?

То есть при зажатой мышки добавлялся класс и так-же при зажатой удалялся?

```js
let but = document.querySelectorAll('.but');

const handler = e =>
  e.buttons === 1 && e.target.classList.contains('but')
  ? e.target.classList.add('active')
  : e.target.classList.remove('active');


for (let i = 0; i < but.length; i++) {
  but[i].addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
  but[i].addEventListener('mousemove', handler);
}
```

```css
.but {
  display: inline-block;
  background: mediumvioletred;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="but">1</div>
<div class="but">2</div>
<div class="but">3</div>
<div class="but">4</div>
```

Comment: То, что вы хотите, невозможно реализовать, чтобы при этом механизм был очевиден. По той простой причине, что нельзя понять, юзер кликнул чтобы выделить или убрать выделение)) Можно сделать выделение при любом зажатом наведении. И отдельную кнопку сброса.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Как это не возможно? Много раз видел в приложениях такое. Просто не могу понять как это реализовать. Если надо видео на такие приложения сделаю

Comment: что такое "выделялись элементы"

Comment: в вопросе, реализуй поведение "без зажатой". и не забудь указать желаемую клавишу

Comment: Потому что как не кручу, получается неудобная хрень) Зажали в первый раз: Должно выделятся всё... но не отпустив если поведут обратно - должно сбрасываться. Зажали второй раз: Начать выделение или сбрасывание?) А там еще захочется сделать переключение по клику... Вижу вариант, всегда выделять при зажатой мышке, и сбрасывать, если зажали вместе с ctrl / cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает криво-косо, но все равно.

```js
let isMouseDown = false;
let mouseDownTarget = null;

document.body.onmousedown = function(e) {
  mouseDownTarget = e.target;
  mouseDownTarget.closest(".block") && mouseDownTarget.closest(".block").classList.toggle('active');
  
  
  isMouseDown = e.button === 0;
}

document.body.onmouseup = function(e) {
  isMouseDown = e.button === 0 ? false : isMouseDown;
}

document.querySelector('.block-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  isMouseDown && 
      e.target.closest(".block") &&
      e.target.closest(".block") !== mouseDownTarget.closest(".block") &&
      e.target.closest(".block").classList.toggle('active');
});

document.querySelector('.block-container').addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  isMouseDown && e.target.closest(".block") && e.target.closest(".block").classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.block-container {
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #122;
  border: 2px solid #122;
}

.active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-container"><div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тот что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: mediumvioletred;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">

import { html, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html?module';

const length = 4;

test(elList => {
    elList.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
        el.classList.toggle('active');
    }));
});

test(elList => {
    elList.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mousedown', ({ altKey }) => {
        if (altKey)
            el.classList.toggle('active');
    }));
});

test(elList => {
    elList.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        const q = ({ code }) => {
            // console.log({ code })
            if ('KeyS' === code)
                el.classList.add('active');
            if ('KeyD' === code)
                el.classList.remove('active');
        };
        window.addEventListener('keydown', q);
        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            window.removeEventListener('keydown', q);
        });
    }));
});


// --------------------------------------------------------

function btn(q) { return html `<div class="btn">${q}</div>`; }
function genBtnList() { return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => btn(i)); }

function genRoot() {
    const root = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    render(html `${genBtnList()}<hr>`, root);
    return root;
}
function test(f) {
    const root = genRoot();
    const elList = Array.from(root.getElementsByClassName('btn'));
    f(elList);
}

</script>
```